# three action button on a single search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, html

I am building a website on WordPress, there is a search button as seen below in image.
[image]

I want if a user fills "Japan" in search box ...condition:

1. If the user clicks on the search button then show all result of "Japan" in website (which is done)
2. If the user clicks on the YouTube icon then videos related to "Japan" are shown
3. If the user clicks on the Wikipedia Link then all information of "Japan" on Wikipedia is shown.

That means that the user can enter anything in search and then search that keyword:

- on the site, or
- on YouTube, or
- on Wikipedia.

The single keyword should work for all buttons.

Comment: and what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. First of all, I would try to make it somewhat more clear what you actually want to do. 
As of this, there might be a risk that I misunderstood you, but if I understood you correctly, this is my answer:

You have three buttons:

Html:

```
<div>
    <button id="wikiButton">Wiki icon</button>
    <button id="youtubeButton">Youtube icon</button>
    <button id="searchButton">Search locally</button>
</div>
```

script:

```
document.getElementById('wikiButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
Do wiki thing
}

document.getElementById('youtubeButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
Do youtube thing
}

document.getElementById('searchButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
Do locally search thing
}
```

Alternatively you could assign an onclick="doThis()" handler to each button, which each holds a function that does what you want.

Comment: Yes I am making a common search filed for 3 buttons 1. local search 2. youtube search 3. wiki search.

Comment: I can't comment on your other comment, apparently. I am not sure what you mean by "but i am unable to make same search field for other two please someone help me"

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?